# How do I solve psycopg2 error when trying to run in local server?

Tags: python, django

So I have deployed my project using AWS EC2. I was trying to run the application in my local server as well, for testing. But then I got the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Envs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user\Envs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Envs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\user\Envs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Envs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\user\Envs\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError
```

I have this in `settings.py`

```
import os
from .local_settings import PG_HOST

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME' : 'myDB',
        'USER' : 'Manager',
        'PASSWORD' : '###password###',
        'HOST' : PG_HOST,
        'PORT' : '',
    }
}
```

And this in `local_settings.py`. (NOT used in the AWS server)

```
PG_HOST = ''
```

What do you think is wrong? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Where is the postgresql server installed? If it's on the same machine as Django you must use `PG_HOST = "localhost"`.

Comment: Thanks. You mean in ```local_settings.py```?

Comment: Yes, either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.